# Object of class CURLFile could not be converted to string

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

How to achieve an image upload via cURL?
I am using a sandbox api for convert pdf file to .txt file. If i use "https://s3.amazonaws.com/sample.pdf" path of pdf for `$sourceFile variable` then its working fine. But if i use system path "test.pdf" then it's not working.
I was trying to through `curl_file_create`, but it gives the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class CURLFile could not be
> converted to string in line.

I am using PHP Version 7.3.0

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$endpoint = "https://api.xxx.com/v1/jobs";
$apiKey = "GiVU******FR48H";
$sourceFile = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/sample.pdf";//new CurlFile("test.pdf");
$targetFormat = "txt";


$postData = array(
  "source_file" => $sourceFile,
  "target_format" => $targetFormat
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":");
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($body, true);
echo "Response:\n---------\n";
echo"<pre>";
print_r($response);
?>

Response: ---------
Array
(
    [id] => 8442473
    [key] => GiVU******FR48H
    [status] => initialising
    [sandbox] => 
    [created_at] => 2019-11-12T10:35:01Z
    [finished_at] => 
    [import] => Array
        (
            [id] => 671784
            [url] => https://s3.amazonaws.com/sample.pdf
            [status] => initialising
        )

    [target_files] => Array
        (
        )

    [target_format] => txt
    [credit_cost] => 0
)
```

Above example give me output as fine as well. If i replace `amazonaws` from `system path` then it doesn't gives any response.

Comment: You're missing the content type; `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));`

Answer (score 2):

`CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` is always set to `false` and curl expects files to be passed as string (`@/path/to/file`) because of it. In your case the code sends files as objects because it's using `curl_file_create()` when available.

When `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` is set to `false`, you should not use `curl_file_create()` (it's flag for backwards compatibility).

Also, try to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` after `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` ([see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646653/curl-not-sending-file-to-api-call/42973207#42973207)).

PHP 5.x is [not supported anymore](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) and I suggest to get rid of the old syntax (`@/path/to/file` and `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD = false`) and always use `curl_file_create()`.

Comment: I see multiple issues:
1) You do not set `@` in front of the path, 2) `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` is set after `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` (you missed that part from my answer).

Try to fix those and then update with the result.

Comment: i have implemented both methods and updated code. I haven't received  any error but i didn't get any response from api. I used `new CurlFile` class method instead of @filename because `@filename` has been deprecated. When i use `amazonaws` path then it provides response.

Comment: I run your script and get the message - [message] => the size of file exceeds the maximum file size cap for the current plan. And I delete this option - curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);

Comment: @Martin since you switched to new upload method (`CURLFile`), you do not need to set `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` anymore. Remove it. I'm not really sure what's happening in your case, can you post the response in both cases as well? I suspect that the `amazonaws` request just send the URL as a string.

Comment: @Dmitry that looks like a server limit, the upload script is probably working.

Comment: @Luxian I updated code and you also can check it just copy and paste. If it's server limit then why it return response when i use `amazonaws` path and in case of system pdf doesn't return response?

Comment: @Martin the server limit was a reply to @Dmitry. In the current code I see that you are still using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` - You do not need that if you use `CurlFile`. Also, you are send an URL as text field, it works differently than a file upload. Let me know how it goes after you remove that line.

Comment: @Luxian after remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` it doesn't  give any error or any response.

Comment: @Martin copy pasted the code and run it on my machine and seems to work (I get file size too big error - I assume upload worked). You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/Luxian/70222e7089c21d880278604a806d466c with some comments where I changed. Also, change your API key, it's now public.

Comment: @Luxian Just i copy and paste. I run it with small size pdf but it doesn't give any error or any response.

Comment: @Martin can you please check this answer on how to get more debug info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/1050554