# How can I find the result of my cURL POST request in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, post

I am new to PHP and am attempting to write a simple cURL POST request in PHP. Thanks to [PHP Pot](https://stackoverflow.com), I have found the following code to use (modifying only the URL and data for my use case).

```
$url = 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = "bot_id=SECRET&text=HI";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

***I am testing this code in a local interactive shell on my PC before uploading it to a server.***

Sadly, the destination server has not been responding as I hoped, so I am currently trying to look into the POST data.

The official [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) recommends curl_getinfo(), but that is where I run into a significant error.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I add the line

```
curl_getinfo($curl);
```

I receive the error message.

> PHP Warning:  Uncaught TypeError: curl_getinfo(): Argument #1
> ($handle) must be of type CurlHandle, string given in php shell code:1

But when I INSTEAD add the line

```
echo $curl;
```

I get the error message.

> PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Object of class CurlHandle could not be
> converted to string in php shell code:1

This seems bizarre to me. PHP thinks it is a string when I call it a CurlHandle object and vice versa. I would appreciate any guidance to help me get this working! I have not tried much because PHP and its libraries are unfamiliar. There is [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696598/object-of-class-curlfile-could-not-be-converted-to-string), but from what I read in the answers, that issue came from wrong syntax not present in my code.

Comment: You're trying to get information about the cURL handle after closing it with curl_close($curl);.  The curl_getinfo($curl); function should be called after curl_exec($curl); and before curl_close($curl);.

Comment: Are you sure you typed `$curl` instead of `$url`?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there's a misunderstanding in how curl_getinfo() is used. The error you're encountering is because curl_getinfo() expects a CurlHandle object, but you're passing the cURL resource directly.

```
$url = 'https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = "bot_id=SECRET&text=HI";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}

$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

print_r($info);

curl_close($curl);
```